# How do I wait through a wait page and then download a PDF, using Python?

Tags: python, http, selenium, pdf, download

### The Problem

I'm trying to download PDF files from a website built over a crotchety old mainframe, and in order to support the traffic the website implements wait pages. The wait page will render and you will spend a few second looking at that instead of the PDF you want, and then it will disappear and you'll go where you want to go.

Here's my scenario:

1. I go to the page.
2. Maybe 33% of the time, I get the wait page. Here's the wait page code:

---

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p><hr /></p>
    </p>
        <div id="waiting-main">
            <p style="text-align: center; margin: 6px 0 15px 0;"><img src="/ns_images2/doblogo_1.jpg" border="0" />
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; line-height: 34px;">Just a moment</p>
            <p style="text-align: left; color: #525252; font-size: 20px; line-height: 22px;">
            Your request is being processed.</br></br>

            Due to the high demand it may take a little longer. You will be directed to the page shortly. Please do not leave this page. Refreshing the page will delay the response time. We apologize for the delay.</br></br>

            ...[snipped for brevity]...

            </p>

        </div>

    </div>

</body></html>
```

---

3. The wait page exits out and I load the following HTML:

---

```
<html><body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38)"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/CofoDocumentContentServlet?passjobnumber=null&amp;cofomatadata1=cofo&amp;cofomatadata2=M&amp;cofomatadata3=000&amp;cofomatadata4=092000&amp;cofomatadata5=M000092531.PDF&amp;requestid=5" type="application/pdf"><div id="annotationContainer"><style>#annotationContainer {    overflow: hidden;     position: absolute;     pointer-events: none;     top: 0;     left: 0;     right: 0;     bottom: 0;     display: -webkit-box;     -webkit-box-align: center;     -webkit-box-pack: center; } .annotation {     position: absolute;     pointer-events: auto; } textarea.annotation {     resize: none; } input.annotation[type='password'] {     position: static;     width: 200px;     margin-top: 100px; } </style></div></body></html>
```

---

4. I download the PDF document locally. The end!

### My attempted solution

Not knowing that `selenium` doesn't really support PDFs (or does it?), this is my approach:

```
_driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

... 
req_string = ...[a very long URL]...
_driver.get(req_str)
...

try:
    WebDriverWait(_driver, 10).until(
        # Cannot use:
        # lambda a: not a.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "waiting-main"))
        # Because:
        # https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2012/07/12/how-to-webdriverwait/
        # Which suggests this working alternative.
        lambda s: len(s.find_elements(By.ID, "waiting-main")) == 0
    )
finally:
    _driver.save_screenshot("test.png") # Maybe?
    # How do I get the actual PDF code? :/
```

### The question

I can't see a way to do this with selenium. So my question is:

**How can I load a page, wait through a wait page, and then download the PDF that comes afterwards using Python (2.7)?**

Alternatively, if this *is* possible with selenium, how can I do it?

### The example

[The link on this page exemplifies my problem.](http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/COsByLocationServlet?requestid=4&allbin=1006360)

### The workaround

For now I'm using:

```
r = requests.get(req_str)
while "waiting-main" in r.text:
    time.sleep(5)
    r = requests.get(req_str)
```

No word yet on how well it works...

### The page

[image]

Comment: you can use `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(something_to_disappear)` to wait until your loader window closed. As for second part, I'm not sure I understand correctly `"PDF that comes afterwards"`... What you mean?

Comment: My description is hampered by a non-total understanding of the problem that I'm trying to address, unfortunately. I've updated it to try and make my question more clear - feedback welcome!

Comment: If you look closely, you'll notice the [pdf](http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/CofoDocumentContentServlet?passjobnumber=null&cofomatadata1=cofo&cofomatadata2=M&cofomatadata3=000&cofomatadata4=092000&cofomatadata5=M000092531.PDF) actually has a URL which you can hit directly. If you can figure out how that URL is constructed, you can shortcircuit the entire process.

Comment: This is exactly the link that I'm hitting, actually; the `CofoDocumentContentServlet` is what occasionally serves the wait notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the page source consistently using requests, this will get the pdf link and save it:

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin

# gets the page when you click the pdf link in your browser
post_url = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/CofoJobDocumentServlet"
base = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/"
r = requests.get("http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/COsByLocationServlet?requestid=4&allbin=1006360")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
# parse the form key/value pairs
form_data = {inp["name"]: inp["value"] for inp in soup.select("form[action=CofoJobDocumentServlet] input")}
# post to from data
nr = requests.post(post_url, data=form_data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(nr.content)

# get the link to the pdf to download
pdf = urljoin(base, soup.select_one("iframe")["src"])

# save pdf to file.
with open("out.pdf","wb") as out:
    out.write(requests.get(pdf).content)
```

If you are experiencing the waits issues, you can wait until the form is visible with selenium and pass the source to bs4:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def wait(dr, x, t):
    element = WebDriverWait(dr, t).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, x))
    )
    return element

dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
dr.get("http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/COsByLocationServlet?requestid=4&allbin=1006360")

wait(dr, "//form[@action='CofoJobDocumentServlet']", 30)

post_url = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/CofoJobDocumentServlet"
base = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(dr.page_source)

form_data = {inp["name"]: inp["value"] for inp in soup.select("form[action=CofoJobDocumentServlet] input")}

nr = requests.post(post_url, data=form_data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(nr.content)

pdf = urljoin(base, soup.select_one("iframe")["src"])

with open("out.pdf","wb") as out:
    out.write(requests.get(pdf).content)
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure if this solves my issue. What relation does `requests.get(pdf)` have to the wait? Isn't that a separate process that will trip the wait time up again?

Comment: @ResMar, which request causes a wait?

Comment: Any request to a webpage in their interface can generate a wait page. That is, both attempting to load the page containing the list of PDFs and loading the PDFs themselves can generate it.

I ended up using a dumb five second rule wait time in case I hit a wait page, source code [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/nyc-construction-timeline/blob/master/co_reader.py).

Answer (score 1):

I would just ignore the wait page. Find a specific element that exists on the download page that does NOT exist on the wait page and wait for it. Just make sure you wait long enough that the wait page will for sure be gone (maybe 30s or more? You might have to try it and see how it goes).

From the HTML you provided, it looks like you might be able to wait for the `EMBED` element. I would suggest a `WebDriverWait` and use the CSS Selector, `"embed[name='plugin']"`.

You can find more info on Selenium waits for Python here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

Answer (score 0):

You need set a download path for PDFS and add the option for always open pdf externally

```
driver_path = "path_from_chromedriver"
download_path = "./PdfFolder"
optionsSelenium = Options() // from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
optionsSelenium.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": download_path,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=options)
```

Always a page with PDF appears will only download the content and close the new tab